# Finding the number of children of the predecessor node of a given node in a Binary Search Tree(BST)

Tags: data-structures, binary-trees, search-trees

I have some propositions regarding BSTs , please can someone confirm whether they are true or false:

Question :

> 1.Suppose we have a node $n_1$ with a value $val_1$ i.e $n_1(val_1)$
>
> 2.We wish to find the number of children of the predecessor node of $n_1$ , with respect to inline traversal (That is the number of
>   children of node $n_2(val_2)$ with $val_2$ being the greatest number
>   $val_2 < val_1$)
>
> 3.Assume for simplicity that the BST dosen't have any repetition

Proposition 1: Let $n_1$ have two children .Then $n_2$ has atmost one child i.e the number of children of $n_2$ can't be two

Proposition 2: Let $n_1$ have only one child and $n_1$ is not root ,then also $n_2$ has atmost one child.

Please ascertain whether these propositions are true , but if false can someone provide a counter example ?

Comment: We prefer that you ask only one question per post.  Also, we'd like to see your thoughts and your attempt.  I suggest you work through some examples and see if you can find a counterexample or formulate some idea at why you tink it might be true.

Comment: (Why would presence or absence of a successor node to $n_1$/a right child have *any* relevance to its left? You are not wrong in stating `also`.)

Answer (score 0):

They're both false. Simple counterexamples:

```
Proposition 1

  2
 / \
1   4
   / \
  3   5

n1 = 4
n2 = 2
number of children of n2 : 2
```

```
Proposition 2

  2
 / \
1   4
   /
  3  

n1 = 4
n2 = 2
number of children of n2 : 2
```

Note how the two counter-examples are almost identical. I only changed the number of children of n1 to satisfy your hypotheses; and it had no impact whatsoever on the number of children of n2.

Answer (score 0):

Let us consider the position of the inorder successor of a node in a binary tree. We need to consider two very symmetric cases

- The node has a right child. Then the successor is the first (in inorder) node of that right subtree. It is the most leftmost node, so succ itself has no left child.
- The node has no right child. Then the node is the last (in inorder) node of the left subtree of succ. Hence succ must have a left child.

The existence of a left child for node, and a right child for succ is unimportant. So it is very well possible that both node and its successor both have only a single child.

[image: inorder successor in binary tree]

Regarding the first proposition:
Here $n_1$ is the successor of node $n_2$. If $n_2$   has two children, it has a right child, thus $n_1$ has no left child (left diagram).

Answer (score -1):

The Q is not clear enough for me, an in-order traversal will get u "n2" as the predecessor of "n1" so  what is exactly required???

Regarding ur prepositions:

-P1:         if n1 has 2 children, or just a left child, then n2 is the rightmost leaf of n1's left child

So  **Proposition 1 is  correct**

-P2:
-As stated above, if ***n1 only child is a left child***, ***n2  have atmost only left child***. 
(meaning not just at most 1, but it must be left)

-if n1 has only a right child, then reverse the argument; i.e., n2 is the node n1 is her left child of a right child (search upward for a node smaller than n1.. its parent if it is a right child **does not make a difference if its parent has another left child or not**, parent of parent,....)

For the bold case inside the brackets, ur **second proposition is wrong.**

I'll try to find an example picture, u may search any data structure text book for a complete tree to exhaust all different cases by ur self

Check the example in the second pic in this Q (My mobile is subject to a Denial of Service attack that prevents attaching it here again)

[Ambiguity with the Top View of a binary tree](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/124567/ambiguity-with-the-top-view-of-a-binary-tree)

It is clear that 10 precedes 11, 11 has one right child while 10 has two
 [image]

Comment: I edited the question hope it is clear

Comment: Oh yes, I got it. Propestion1 is right, I think I explained why; I'll check 2.

Comment: I don't think proposition 1 is true.